Evaluate Limit of Faulhaber Formula
Prove or evaluate that:
$$ \lim_{ n \to \infty }\frac{S_{k}(n)}{n^{k+1}}=\frac{1}{k+1}$$
Where
$$S_{n}^k=\sum^{n}_{m=0}m^k$$

So I have noticed that it can be done by proving $S_k(n)$ is a polynomial of degree $n+1$ while the leading coefficient is $\frac{1}{k+1}$, but how do I expand it? Or, if this method is not recommended, can you show me how to prove it?

And here is my incomplete attempt:
$$\sum^n_{m=0}m^k=\sum^{n}_{m=0}{(n-m)^k}=\sum^{n}_{m=0}(n-(n-m))^k=\sum^{n}_{m=0}\sum^{k}_{i=0}\binom{k}{i}n^{k-i}(m-n)^i$$
$$=\sum^{n}_{m=0} \sum^{k}_{i=0} \sum^{i}_{j=0}\binom{k}{i}\binom{i}{j}n^{k-i}m^{j}{(-n)}^{i-j}$$
Edit:
Since the sequence in the denominator is strictly monotone and tending to infinity, we can use stolz theorem.
Using stolz theorem, we get
\begin{align}\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{S_k(n)}{n^{k+1}}=\\\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{S_k({n+1})-S_k(n)}{(n+1)^{k+1}-n^{k+1}}=\\\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(n+1)^k}{(n+1)^{k+1}-n^{k+1}}=\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{k}\binom{k}{i}n^i}{\sum_{i=0}^{k}{\binom{k+1}{i}}n^i}=\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^k+\cdots}{(k+1)n^k+\cdots}=\\
\frac{1}{k+1}
\\\end{align}

It may help to note $\int_0^1 x^k dx=\dfrac1{k+1}$

The simpler approach here is to use Cesaro-Stolz theorem.

@ParamanandSingh Can you demonstrate or write an answer for me? Edit: I tried to use it but cannot proceed further.

I checked your approach at the end which is fine. Why don't you expand the $(n+1)^{k+1}$ in denominator using binomial theorem and a few terms will cancel. Use a similar expansion in numerator for $(n+1)^k$.

You should get something like $\frac{n^k+\dots} {(k+1)n^k+\dots}$ so that desired limit is $1/(k+1)$.

@ParamanandSingh thank you, I updated my new approach and evaluation.

More related questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/478344, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/150391.

You could go a bit further using generalized harmonic numbers
$$S_{n}^k=\sum^{n}_{m=0}m^k=1+H_n^{(-k)}$$
Expanding for large $n$
$$S_{n}^k= (1+\zeta (-k))+n^k
   \left(\frac{n}{k+1}+\frac{1} {2}+\frac{k}{12  n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)$$
$$\frac{S_{k}(n)}{n^{k+1}}=\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac 1{2n}+\frac k{12\,n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$

Here's the start of an answer I made
to a question like yours
about 3 years ago.
The question was closed and deleted,
so I am reposting this.
If
$f_k(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n i^k$
($f_0(n) = n$)
then
$\begin{array}\\
f_k(n+1) 
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i^k\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n} (i+1)^k\\
&=1+ \sum_{i=1}^{n} (i+1)^k\\
&=1+ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}i^j\\
&=1+  \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^j\\
&=1+  \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}f_j(n)\\
\text{so}\\
(n+1)^k
&=f_{k}(n+1)-f_k(n)\\
&=1+  \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}f_j(n)-f_k(n)\\
&=1+  \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \binom{k}{j}f_j(n)\\
\end{array}
$
or
$kf_{k-1}(n)
=(n+1)^k-1-\sum_{j=0}^{k-2} \binom{k}{j}f_j(n)
$
or
$(k+1)f_{k}(n)
=(n+1)^{k+1}-1-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \binom{k+1}{j}f_j(n)
$
Examples:
If $k=1$
then
$\begin{array}\\
2f_{1}(n)
&=(n+1)^{2}-1-f_0(n)\\
&=n^2+2n+1-1-n\\
&=n^2+n\\
\end{array}
$
If $k=2$
then
$\begin{array}\\
3f_{2}(n)
&=(n+1)^{3}-1-f_0(n)-3f_1(n)\\
&=n^3+3n^2+3n+1-1-n-3(n^2+n)/2\\
&=\dfrac{2n^3+6n^2+6n+2-2-2n-3(n^2+n)}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{2n^3+3n^2+n}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{2}\\
\end{array}
$
Since
$(k+1)f_{k}(n)
=(n+1)^{k+1}-1-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \binom{k+1}{j}f_j(n)
$,
$f_k(n)
\lt \dfrac{(n+1)^{k+1}}{k+1}
$.
Also,
$f_k(n)$
is a polynomial of degree $k+1$.
with constant term $0$.
(I have more details
on getting the coefficients
of the polynomial,
but I'll stop here.)

Using Cesaro-Stolz, as you pointed out, we just need to evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty} \tfrac{1}{n+1-n\big(\tfrac{n}{n+1}\big)^k}$. So it suffices to show that $\lim_
{n\to\infty} n\big(1-(\tfrac{n}{n+1})^k\big) = k$.
$\big(\tfrac{n}{n+1}\big)^k=\big(1-\tfrac{1}{n+1}\big)^k=\sum_{j=0}^k {k\choose j}1^j(-1)^{k-j}\tfrac{1}{(n+1)^{k-j}}=1-\tfrac{k}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}A$ for some expression $A$ that is bounded as $n\to\infty$.
So, $\lim_{n\to\infty} n\big(1-(\tfrac{n}{n+1})^k\big)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\big(k\tfrac{n}{n+1}-A\tfrac{n}{(n+1)^2}\big)=k$.

$\sum_{i=1}^n i^k=\sum_{j=1}^{k+1} c_jn^j$
Since we are dividing the $n^{k+1}$, the only non-zero term is the coefficient of $n^{k+1}$.
$(n+1)^k= \sum_{j=1}^{k+1} c_j[(n+1)^j-n^j]=\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}\sum_{q=0}^{j-1}c_j\binom{j}{q}n^q$
Coefficient for $n^k$ term has to be th same on both side, i.e. 1.
$c_{k+1}\binom{k+1}{k}=1 \implies c_{k+1}\frac{(k+1)!}{k!1!}\implies c_{k+1}=\frac{1}{k+1}$

By far the simplest approach is to use Riemann sums
$$
\frac{1}{n^{k+1}} \sum_{m=0}^n m^k = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{m=0}^n \left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^k \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \int_0^1 x^k \text dx = \frac{1}{k+1}.
$$
